# JavaFX 2.0 TabPane Application set tab as default on run

Tags: tabs, javafx-2

Hy everyone, i am working on a JavaFX 2.0 App and i am wondering if i can somehow when i am opening the application, the selected tab to be the second one? I mean i open the application and instead of viewing the first tab, i will see the second one with its content!

I am looking for something like this because i am working with fxml files and i have buttons in the first and in the second tab, and when i will click a button from the second tab the fxml content will be replaced by another fxml, which means the second one will be opened but not on the right page. So anyone can help me out here, or anyone know a better idea for replacing the content which is already inside a fxml page(I don't think it can be done)?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[tabPane.getSelectionModel().select(1)](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/TabPane.html#getSelectionModel%28%29)

Comment: I want to do this from fxml if it is possible! Thanks!

Comment: EDIT: I used it in initialization of the fxml controller and it worked very well. Thanks a lot!